# Bootstrap Panel Header with Link for accordion and formatted Content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, accordion, panel

I am new to Bootstrap and I am looking for solution to create a clickable Panel Header with 3 Columns.

Since now my code looks like:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">
            <a style="display: block" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panelBody<%=trimmedKennzeichen%>">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <h4>t1</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <h4>t2</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <h4>t3</h4>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this is destroying my formatting and the outcome is horrible.

So my Question is how do I get a Panel-Header with formatted Content ( 3 Columns in different horizontal alignments ) and the whole header should be a link to open the panel-body as an accordion should do.

I Hope you can help me :)

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `div.col-*` classes without `div.row` as parent.

*Because how can you have columns without row. First there should be one row then you add columns in it ;)*

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title">
        <a style="display: block" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-parent="#accordion" href="#panelBody<%=trimmedKennzeichen%>">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <h4>t1</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <h4>t2</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                  <h4>t3</h4>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some normal rules:

> 1. Columns are always within a row.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</row>
```

> 2. Column never has Columns within. If you want to add more columns within one column follow rule 1. Add row first then add columns in it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- Never do like this -->
        <div class="col-md-8"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- Do Like this: -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </row>
    </div>    
</div>
```

> 3. Never make row within row. row always has columns within.

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Never do like this: -->
    <div class="row"></row>
    <div class="row"></row>
</div>
```

Comment: thx alot. It works. 
Only further problem is that the panels are not closing by clicking on the header again. The only way to collapse one panel is to open another one

Comment: So for formatting problem follow above mentioned rules. For closing and opening issue you can refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/R6EAW/12/)

glad that my answer solve your problem. Thanks foraccepting. I would appreciate if you up vote that as well. Thanks.